# Large Deviations Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

Let $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ be i.i.d random variables on $\left(\Omega,\mathcal A, \mathbb P\right)$, $X_1$ with mean $\mu$, and

$$
L(\lambda) =
\begin{cases}
\log\mathbb E\left(e^{\lambda X_1}\right)<\infty, & \text{if }\mathbb E\left(e^{\lambda X_1}\right)<\infty \\
+\infty, & \text{otherwise, }
\end{cases}
$$

Show that for any $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, $$L(\lambda)\geq \lambda\mu$$

---

The infinity case is clear, so we are trying to show that

$$\log\mathbb E\left(e^{\lambda X_1}\right)\geq \lambda \mu$$

so,

$$\mathbb E\left(e^{\lambda X_1}\right)\geq e^{\lambda\mu}$$

Jenson's Inequality states that

$$\mathbb E\left[\varphi(X_1)\right]\geq\varphi\left(\mathbb E\left[X_1\right]\right)$$

Comment: Jenson's Inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality

Answer (score 1):

[Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) states that $\varphi(\mathbb E(Y))\leqslant \mathbb E(\varphi(Y))$ where $\varphi\colon\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ is convex and $Y$ is a non-negative random variable.

Here, when $\mathbb E(e^{\lambda X_1})$ is finite, use Jensen's inequality with $\varphi(s):=\exp(s)$.